# Foreign Table Has No Generated Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a user table that has a bunch of attributes that I can call with a method (This was generated by devise):

```
user.name
```

However I made another table, as the user has_one server.  These are linked by rails' foreign key magic. I want to be able to call methods like I do with the user table, by using methods, but it always throws this error when trying to call user.server.created_at

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `created_at' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x000001036e5a38>
```

I then tried to do this:

```
user.server[:created_at]
```

And that threw this error:

```
Typerror: can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

I heard attr_accessor might be appropriate to create methods, but I'm not really sure where to start using it with Rails, and if that would even be a good idea.

EDIT:

I'm trying to end up with something like this:

```
time_left = (Time.now.to_i - current_server[:created_at].to_i)
```

Except with correct syntax.  Created_at does exist and is being written with the correct time.

User Model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :server

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

Server Model:

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your model definitions (User.rb / Server.rb), and schema definitions "users" table and "servers" table.

Answer (score 1):

Does the created_at column actually exist in the table named servers?

The second syntax is just wrong.  I don't know why it gives that error, but I dont expect it to work anyway.

Posting more full code might help debug.

Comment: Didn't realize that the models contained an attr_accessible method Do'h! Thanks everyone!